# What regular expression do I need to change [^ +]\+[^ =+] into " + " in Codeblocks?

Tags: regex

Throughout my source, I've scattered expressions like

```
*(blah+i)
```

and I'd rather they were formatted like

```
*(blah + i)
```

The search expression in my title finds them correctly, but I'm not sure what to put in the 'replace' box to make it keep the matched letters on either side of the '+'.  I'm new to regular expressions.

I tried backreferences, but I'm not 100% sure how to use them.  I tried the following in the find box:

```
([^ +])\+([^=+ ])
```

and this in the replace box:

```
\1 + \2
```

But Codeblocks just says 'no matches found', although the expression in my title works.

Comment: Which regex engine? (This impacts how captured groups are specified in the replacement expression.)

Comment: Your development-environment should be able to perform this formatting for you. (e.g. if you are developing in java using IntelliJ, you can just set this rule in your coding style).

Comment: I agree with @bvdb. You development environment has a much better idea which `+` characters in your code are addition operators, and which are not (because they are in comments or strings, for example). This is something a regex can never know.

Comment: @tomalak Let's assume that comments and strings are not an issue.  I can step through with the find & replace and say yes or no to the replacement.  But I'm just not sure what goes in the 'replace' box.

Comment: If you investigate every potential match manually, you can try something as simple as replacing `\s*\+\s*` with `" + "` (space plus space), or `(\S)\+(\S)` with `"\1 + \2"`.

Comment: @Tomalak Unfortunately, this also matches '++' and, since my source has a billion of these, it's not great.  I tried using tags using the regex in my title, but I'm not 100% sure how they work.